# Elasticsearch copy_to not working on keyword field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to copy two fields onto a third field, which should have the type 'keyword' (because I want to be able to aggregate by it, and do not need to perform a full-text search)

```
PUT /test/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    "first": {
      "copy_to": "full_name",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "last": {
      "copy_to": "full_name",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "full_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

I then post a new document:

```
POST /test/_doc
{
  "first": "Bar",
  "last": "Foo"
}
```

And query it using the composite field `full_name`:

```
GET /test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_name": "Bar Foo" 
    }
  }
}
```

And no hits are returned.

If the type of the composite field `full_name` were `text` then it works as expected and described in the docs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

Is it not possible to copy onto a keyword-type field?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `match` query - When you index your docs you use keyword type which according to the [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) are "...only searchable by their exact value."

However when you query that field you use `match` query which is using the standard analyzer which, among other stuff, also does lower-casing which causes your terms to not match nothing.

You have few options I can think of in this case:

1. Change the field type to `text` which will perform the same analysis as the `match` query.
2. Create a custom field type with custom analyzer which will perform lower casing
3. Don't query more than a single term at a time and use `term` query instead of `match`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type of destination field of copy_to  must be text type.